# Server-side rendering with redux and immutable.js errors on MapStateToProp contents

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, immutable.js

I am currently working on server rendering with `react v0.14`, `redux v3.0`, `immutable v3.7.6` but I've run into a few issues in making that happen. Whenever I go to a page of my app that contains `mapStateToProps` I receive an error in the console depending on the piece of the state that says something like `Uncaught TypeError: e.dashboard.shoppingCart.get is not a function`.

The `dashboard.shoppingCart.get` is the value for the state that I'm setting in the `mapStateToProps` and the `.get()` refers to the `immutable.js` method on `Map`. I'm not sure what seems to be causing this error and it kills any javascript in the app, making nothing work.

### Server

```js
import http from 'http';
import React from 'react';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './../common/store/store.js';

import fs from 'fs';
import { createPage, write, writeError, writeNotFound, redirect } from './server-utils.js';
import routes from './../common/routes/rootRoutes.js';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;



function renderApp(props, res) {
  var store = configureStore();
  var markup = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RoutingContext {...props}/>
    </Provider>
  );
  const initialState = store.getState();
  var html = createPage(markup, initialState);
  write(html, 'text/html', res);
}

http.createServer((req, res) => {

  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    write('haha', 'text/plain', res);
  }

  // serve JavaScript assets
  else if (/__build__/.test(req.url)) {
    fs.readFile(`.${req.url}`, (err, data) => {
      write(data, 'text/javaScript', res);
    })
  }

  // handle all other urls with React Router
  else {
    match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      if (error)
        writeError('ERROR!', res);
      else if (redirectLocation)
        redirect(redirectLocation, res);
      else if (renderProps)
        renderApp(renderProps, res);
      else
        writeNotFound(res);
    });
  }

}).listen(PORT)
console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`)
```

### Client

```js
import React from 'react';
import { match, Router } from 'react-router';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import routes from './../common/routes/rootRoutes.js';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './../common/store/store.js';
import './../common/styles/main.scss';


const { pathname, search, hash } = window.location;
const location = `${pathname}${search}${hash}`;

const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
const store = configureStore(initialState);



// calling `match` is simply for side effects of
// loading route/component code for the initial location
match({ routes, location }, () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router routes={routes} history={createHistory()} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
});
```

### DashCart

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import DashCartItem from './DashCartItem.jsx';
import * as DashCartActions from './../../actionCreators/Dashboard/DashShoppingCart.js';

function DashCart (props) {

  var DashCartItemsList = props.cartSneakers.map((sneaker, key ) => {
    return <DashCartItem sneaker={sneaker} key={key} remove={props.actions.removeSneakerFromCart}></DashCartItem>;
  });

  var price = () => {
    var prices = [];
    props.cartSneakers.map((sneaker) => prices.push(sneaker.get('price')));
    var result = prices.reduce((sneakerOne, sneakerTwo) => sneakerOne + sneakerTwo, 0);
    return (result !== 0) ? 'Estimated Total: $' + result : 'Cart is Empty!';
  }

  var totalList = props.cartSneakers.map((sneaker, key) => {
    return <div key={key}><h4 className="sneaker">{sneaker.get('sneakerName')}</h4> <h4 className="price"> ${sneaker.get('price')}</h4></div>
  })

  var checkOut = () => props.actions.checkout(props.cartSneakers);

  return (
    <div className="DashCart">
      <div className="col-sm-9 segment nopadding">
        {DashCartItemsList}
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-3 nopadding checkOut">
        <div className="panel panel-default">
          <div className="panel-heading">
            <h4 className="panel-title">Cart Estimated Subtotal</h4>
          </div>
            {totalList}
            <hr></hr>
            <h4 className="total">{price()}</h4>
            <h4 className="total"></h4>
          </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={checkOut} className="checkout btn btn-default">CheckOut</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    cartSneakers: state.dashboard.shoppingCart.get('cartSneakers')
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(DashCartActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(DashCart);
```

### Dashboard Reducer

```js
    export const dashboardReducer = combineReducers({
      userSneakers: dashSharedReducer,
      shoppingCart: dashShoppingCartReducer,
      trades: dashTradesReducer,
      orderHistory: dashOrderHistoryReducer,
      events: dashEventsReducer,
      sneakerTracking: dashSneakerTrackingReducer,
      shippingInfo: dashShippingReducer,
      billingInfo: dashBillingReducer,
      accountInfo: dashAccountSettingsReducer
    });
    //ShoppingCart Reducer
    export function dashShoppingCartReducer (state = sample, action ) {
      switch (action.type) {

        case CHECKOUT:
          return handleCheckout(state, action.cartPayload);

        case REMOVE_SNEAKER_FROM_CART:
          return handleRemoveSneakerFromCart(state, action.sneakerToRemove);

        case RECEIVE_SNEAKERS_IN_CART:
          return handleReceiveSneakersInCart(state, action.cartSneakers);

        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does your dashboard reducer look like?

Comment: I put it up, but I don't think that is the issue as it works seamlessly when in my original codebase that is being rendered client-side.

Comment: The problem is that somehow somewhere in your code you're not creating an Immutable Map and therefore `e.state.dashboard.shoppingCart.get` is not a function.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because it worked on my client-side repo client side and I did not change any of the reducers implementations when moving to server-side rendering. I was thinking it was an issue with hydrating the store in the client.js file

Comment: As I said, somewhere somehow youre not creating a map.

Comment: Ok i'll keep looking around my reducers to see if this is the cause.

Comment: Im convinced that you are right. For some reason all my Immutable data structures are being converted to regular JS data structures. This is not the case in my client-side code as I have them side by side. This is so odd, its the same exact code, but something seems to be changing it.

Comment: Okay, so I solved the problem. My server setup was automatically causing/coercing my immutable data-structures to JS when rendering them statically. So I hade to add `I.fromJS(state)` before passing it into `configure store` both on the server and client. Thank you for pointing out them not being immutable I had over-looked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution to my problem. The Server implementation for my app was automatically coercing the `immutable` data structures which was causing `get()` not to be recognized and throwing an error that halted all Javascript in the app.

To solve this you have to make sure that after calling `getState()` on both the server and client to convert the state to immutable data structures before passing it into `configureStore()`. To do this simply add the the following line into server and client files:

`var state = I.fromJS(initialState)` and pass that into the store `configureStore(state)`.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804769/how-to-do-server-side-rendering-with-redux-immutable-js] Pls Drop your suggestion I am pretty confused