# How to do server side rendering with Redux + Immutable js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I would like to Use Immutable js with my App .But It's Kinda difficult for server side rendering It throws me a error like this

> TypeError: state.allPosts.toJS is not a function

Home.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as allPosts from '../Redux/Actions/AllPosts_action'



class Home extends Component{

    renderAllPosts(){
        const {posts} = this.props;

        return(
            posts.postArr.map(({id,title,body}) => {
                return <li key={id}>{title}</li>
            })
        )
    }
    render(){



        return(
            <div>
                <Helmet>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <title>My Title</title>
                    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/Home.css" />
                </Helmet>
                {this.renderAllPosts()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


Home.fetchData = ({store,location, params, history}) => store.dispatch(allPosts.getAllPosts());

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return{
      posts:state.allPosts.toJS() //This throws the error
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getAllPosts:() => dispatch(allPosts.getAllPosts())
    }
};



export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Client/Index.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import configureStore from './Redux/Store/configureStore';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import MainRoutes from './MainRouter';
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';



//window.__STATE__ this is my server rendered state But it not in the immutable form

const store = configureStore(window.__STATE__);


console.log(store.getState())
const RenderApp = (Component) => {
    render(
        <AppContainer>

            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component store={store}/>
            </Provider>

        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    )
};



RenderApp(MainRoutes);

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./MainRouter', () => {
        const nextMainRoutes = require('./MainRouter');
        RenderApp(nextMainRoutes);
    });
}
```

Server.js

```
app.get('*',(req,res,next) => {

    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'));

    match({routes:routes(),location:req.url},(err,redirectLocation,renderProps) => {

    //    Err Handling
        if (redirectLocation) {
            return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        }
        if (!renderProps) {
            return next(new Error('Missing render props'))
        }
        const components = renderProps.components;
        const Comp = components[components.length - 1].WrappedComponent;

        const fetchData = (Comp && Comp.fetchData) || (() => Promise.resolve())


        const initialState = {}

        const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

        const { location, params, history } = renderProps

        fetchData({store,location,params,history}).then(() => {

            const body = renderToStaticMarkup(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                </Provider>
            )

            const state = store.getState();

            let head = Helmet.rewind();

            res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>
               ${head.title}
                ${head.meta}
                ${head.link}
            </head>
            <body>
              <div id="app" >${body}</div>
              <script>window.__STATE__=${JSON.stringify(state)}</script>

              <script src="/static/vendor.js"></script>
                <script src="/static/app.js"></script>
            </body>
          </html>`)


        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err,'From Store Fetch')
        })

    })


});
```

UPDATE

As commented below I searched and finally end up like this .

```
The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of "String". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "allPosts", "routing
```

This is my Updated Code

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import configureStore from './Redux/Store/configureStore';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import MainRoutes from './MainRouter';



function toJS(js) {
    for (let el in js) {
        if (!isPlainObj(js[el]) && !Array.isArray(js[el]))
            js[el] = js[el].toJS()
    }
    return js
}

function isPlainObj(value) {
    return value && (value.constructor === Object || value.constructor === undefined);
}

const initialState = JSON.stringify(toJS(window.__STATE__))
const store = configureStore(initialState);


console.log(store.getState())
const RenderApp = (Component) => {
    render(
        <AppContainer>

            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component store={store}/>
            </Provider>

        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    )
};



RenderApp(MainRoutes);

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./MainRouter', () => {
        const nextMainRoutes = require('./MainRouter');
        RenderApp(nextMainRoutes);
    });

}
```

Comment: Where do you define the function `toJS` ??

Comment: Look my Home.js component mapStateToProps funtion

Comment: I didn't ask where you use it, but where you define it. It's a function, it must be somewhere in your code: `function toJS () { /* */ }`

Comment: You're not actually defining it there, you're just invoking it. Have you defined it on the `posts` object elsewhere in your code? 

**edited** Or perhaps you could define it as a general method that takes an object and outputs something in the desired format (though, tbh, you might be overthinking this).

Comment: Ya! You are right But I don't Know how to define it Like I literally Don't know what toJs() will do .But I wanna Use Immutable js..

Comment: @Ematipico How to fix it ? Any idea :(

Comment: Just searching, I found this on reduxjs docs http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html#never-use-tojs-in-mapstatetoprops

Comment: Ha ! I could not find anything rather than this advice **Don't use .toJs() coz its expensive** @Ematipico

Comment: @Ematipico I found Something My question Updated